# Getting png by the coordinates in C++

Tags: c++, c, png

I would like to know is there any library for C++ or C which allows to get png-image by coordinates. For example: 
I have opened png file, and I need to get only the parf of it which starts from

```
x = 5
y = 5
w = 10
h = 10
and so on
```

So what library allows to do such kind of operations?
Thanks on advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Magic++](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick++.php):

```
#include <Magick++.h> 
using namespace Magick; 

void main()
{
    Image image;
    image.read( "in.png" );

    // Crop the image to specified size (width, height, xOffset, yOffset)
    image.crop( Geometry(10, 10, 5, 5) );

    // Write the image to a file
    image.write( "out.png" ); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most libraries will do this for you.  In OpenCV:

Headers:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
```

Code:

```
IplImage *im = cvLoadImage("input.png");
cvSetImageROI(im, cvRect(x, y, w, h));
cvShowImage("output.png", im);
```

Comment: is it possible to do it using openGL?

Comment: AFAIK OpenGL is not capable of loading/saving images at all. OpenGL decoupled from any image I/O stuff, and can thus not be used for such a task.

Answer (score 1):

Like @misha said, most libraries have this functionality. The [boost.GIL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/gil/doc/index.html) library can do it too:

```
#include <boost/gil/gil_all.hpp>
// I need this bugfix to compile against libpng 1.5, your mileage may vary
#define int_p_NULL (int*)NULL
// done with the fix
#include <boost/gil/extension/io/png_dynamic_io.hpp>
int main()
{
    boost::gil::rgb8_image_t img;
    png_read_image("in.png", img);
    png_write_view("out.png", subimage_view(const_view(img), 5, 5, 10, 10));
}
```

Only needs `-lpng` when compiling.